# I can't download the puppeter, after using command npm install

Tags: javascript, dependencies, syntax-error, deprecated

I'm trying to install puppeteer and every time I get the same error, I already installed Chromium and puppeteer-core, my node version is v20.4.0 and my npm version is 9.8.1, anyone has some solution please?

PS: I already tried delete the node_modules and the package-lock.json

````
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\SC by IchanZX V3\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:415
npm ERR!       const err = new Error(
npm ERR!                   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\SC by IchanZX V3\node_modules\progress\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
npm ERR!     at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:415:19)
npm ERR!     at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:665:18)
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1034:27)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SC by IchanZX V3\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\install.js:24:36)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\SC by IchanZX V3\\node_modules\\progress\\package.json',
npm ERR!   requestPath: 'progress'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v20.4.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Ravabox\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-12T10_31_57_338Z-debug-0.log```
````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to install version LTS of Node. It is more stable, it has fewer errors and the software is maintained for a more extended period of
time. At this moment it is 18.17.1 (includes npm 9.6.7). You can find this version [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download).